# Как анимировать изменение высоты и ширины блока при помощи transition: width, height

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

**Для примера:**

```js
$('.test').on('click', function() {
  $(this).text() === 'Длинный текст, длинный тексть длинный текст' ? $(this).text('Короткий текст') : $(this).text('Длинный текст, длинный тексть длинный текст');
});
```

```css
.test {
  background-color: #1aafff;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">
  Нажимать сюда
</div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/animate-heightwidth-to-auto/

Comment: @soledar10, Спасибо! Но не совсем то.